# Stripping a response

Tags: c#, sql

I have the below response from a webservice i have consumed from a partner. I want to insert the string into a database and the column is a varchar. I want to strip it and remove the curly brackets, double quotes and the colons, how can i do it or how will i insert it into my database column which is varchar? The language i an using is C#.

```
{"Currency":"USD","DueAmount":"776.38","DueDate":"2014-11-18T00:00:00+02:00"}
```

Comment: It would be actually easier to keep string in JSON as it is and store in DB so you can actually use it later...

Comment: So you are not deserializing the response from the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say don't strip it.  As a JSON string this is much more parsable in the future when you need to get to the individual elements (e.g., `JsonValue.Parse` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>`).

If you must get rid of the JSON and mash the fields together...  Maybe:

```
strVal.Replace("{\"","").Replace("\":\"","").Replace("\",\"",",").Replace("\"}","");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a JSON response and you can parse json to map it to the actual class.

Create a class:

```
 public class Reponse
 {
    public string Currency {get; set;}
    public decimal DueAmount {get; set;}
    public DateTime DueDate {get; set;}

}
```

Then in your code do something like that to map the response to the above class.

```
 Response ObjResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(ContentFromWebservice);
```

Hope this helps ..

Answer (score 0):

String.Replace function will work to replace {} and ". Regarding what is the problem in varchar to add this string. It should work.